# A list of lists of lists in Python

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

I'm working with the Flask framework in Python, and need to hand off a list of lists to a renderer.

I step through a loop and create a list, sort it, append it to another list, then call the render function with the masterlist, like so:

```
for itemID in itemsArray:
    avgQuantity = getJitaQuantity(itemID)
    lowestJitaSell = getJitaLowest(itemID)
    candidateArray = findLowestPrices(itemID, lowestJitaSell, candidateArray, avgQuantity)
    candidateArray.sort()
    multiCandidateArray.append(candidateArray)
renderPage(multiCandidateArray)
```

My problem is that I need to clear the candidateArray and create a new one each time through the loop, but it looks like the candidateArray that I append to the multiCandidateArray is actually a pointer, not the values themselves.

When I do this:

```
for itemID in itemsArray:
    avgQuantity = getJitaQuantity(itemID)
    lowestJitaSell = getJitaLowest(itemID)
    candidateArray = findLowestPrices(itemID, lowestJitaSell, candidateArray, avgQuantity)
    candidateArray.sort()
    multiCandidateArray.append(candidateArray)
    **del candidateArray[:]**
renderPage(multiCandidateArray)
```

I end up with no values.

Is there a way to handle this situation that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably go with something like:

```
for itemID in itemsArray:
    avgQuantity = getJitaQuantity(itemID)
    lowestJitaSell = getJitaLowest(itemID)
    candidateArray = findLowestPrices(itemID, lowestJitaSell, candidateArray, avgQuantity)
    multiCandidateArray.append(sorted(candidateArray))
```

No need to `del` anything here, and `sorted` returns a new `list`, so even if `FindLowestPrices` is for some reason returning references to the same list (which is unlikely), then you'll still have unique lists in the `multiCandidateArray` (although your unique lists could hold references to the same objects).

Comment: That's perfect, many thanks. Does what I need with fewer lines.

Comment: Actually, I take that back -- if I run the list twice, I end up with the values from the first run through mixed into the second set -- if I run it 3 times, I get all three.

Answer (score 0):

Your code *already* creates a new one each time through the loop.

```
candidateArray = findLowestPrices(...)
```

This assigns a new list to the variable, `candidateArray`.  It should work fine.

When you do this:

```
del candidateArray[:]
```

...you're deleting the contents of the *same list* you just appended to the master list.

Don't think about pointers or variables; just think about objects, and remember nothing in Python is ever implicitly copied.  A list is an object.  At the end of the loop, `candidateArray` names the same list object as `multiCandidateArray[-1]`.  They're different *names* for the same thing.  On the next run through the loop, `candidateArray` becomes a name for a *new* list as produced by `findLowestPrices`, and the list at the end of the master list is unaffected.

I've [written about this before](http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/05/23/python-faq-passing/); the C way of thinking about variables as being predetermined blocks of memory just doesn't apply to Python at all.  Names are moved onto values, rather than values being copied into some fixed number of buckets.

(Also, nitpicking, but Python code generally uses `under_scores` and doesn't bother with types in names unless it's really ambiguous.  So you might have `candidates` and `multi_candidates`.  Definitely don't call anything an "array", since there's an `array` module in the standard library that does something different and generally not too useful.  :))

Comment: And these are also Lists, not Arrays, making my code doubly crappy :]